# Checking connection to Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have some code dependent of Azure Service Bus. I've created an endpoint that checks the availability of my Azure Service Bus topic using the following code:

```cs
var connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("servicebusconnectionstring");
var manager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var sub = manager.GetSubscription("mytopic", "mysubscription");
var count = sub.MessageCount;
```

This actually works, but I have two questions (since I'm constantly experiencing timeouts using this code).

Question 1: Is there an easier/better way of checking Service Bus connectivity from C#?

Question 2: When using the code above, which instances should I configure as singleton in my IoC container? I'm suspecting creating all instances every time I ping this endpoint to cause the timeout, since I don't see problems in my other endpoints where I re-use a `TopicClient`.

Answer (score 1):

Getting `MessageCount` is potentially an expensive operation, especially if the value is high.

You could run a simple operation like a check whether the topic exists:

```cs
var ns = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("...");
ns.TopicExists("mytopic");
```

which will throw an exception (probably `MessagingCommunicationException`) if communication to Service Bus fails.

It's ok to reuse `NamespaceManager` between requests, so you can make it singleton. Not sure if that brings any measurable performance benefit though.